# Symfony 3.2 with LiipImagineBundle not create folder media/cache

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, symfony-3.2, liipimaginebundle

I'm use Symfony 3.2 with LiipImagineBundle 1.8.0 and Nginx with php7 fpm in production. In desenv the webserver is the php built-in server. In desenv works fine and cache dir are created in web folder, but in production not and Symfony return 404 for images. Any idea what that might be? This is my configuration:

**Nginx**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}

location @rewriteapp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
}

location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {

    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    internal;
}

location ~ \.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
        expires 18h;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        access_log off;
    }

    try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
}
```

**Symfony Config**

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
                cache_prefix: "media/cache"


    filter_sets:
        cache: ~

        slide:
            quality: 80
            filters:
                thumbnail: { size: [364, 244]}
                watermark:
                    image: Resources/data/logo.png
                    size: 0.2
                    position: bottomleft
```

**Symfony Routing**

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
```

**Twig filter use**

```
<img src="{{ asset( 'bundles/app/uploads/' ~ image.id ~ '/' ~ image.file )  | imagine_filter('slide')  }}" />
```

**Permissions in media folder created by me.**

```
drwxrwxrwx+  3 root     root  4096 Aug 15 19:05 media
```

Comment: What of OS using (Ubuntu...)?

Comment: @ImanaliMamadiev Yes, Ubuntu 16.04 in Digital Ocean vm.

Comment: asset( 'bundles/app/uploads/' ~ image.id ~ '/' ~ image.file )  | imagine_filter('slide')   how  it look's like in html source ?

Comment: You can see your problems from log: `var/logs/prod.log` or from command `tail -f /var/log/nginx/yoursitename-error...`

Comment: @MichałG this url: http://myhost/media/cache/resolve/slide/bundles/app/uploads/16/fe2d962c4ee1a75a56057f8971de73ba.jpeg

Comment: maybe  stupid  question  , but you have  image  file on give path ? bundles/app/uploads/' ~ image.id ~ '/' ~ image.file

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

In config the correct value of cache_prefix must contais traling slashe

```
liip_imagine:
    resolvers:
        default:
            web_path:
                web_root: "%kernel.root_dir%/../web"
                cache_prefix: "/media/cache"
```